# Three-js Rendering OBJ as Wireframe (Should be rendering faces and shading)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, three.js, 3d

I have imported  a .obj file into Three-js, but it is not rendering the model as expected. The model is rendering as a wireframe and even appears to be adding geometry that does not exist.

I have previewed the object in browser using https://3dviewer.net/ and there were no problems, so I know it is not the object itself.

I added a new MIME type for .obj format (application/octet-stream) to my machine, which didn't seem to make any difference.

```
    var crescentMaterial;
    var crescentTexture;
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    crescentTexture = loader.load(
        'Textures/crescent.png', function () { }, function () {
            renderer.render(scene);
        });

    crescentMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    crescentMaterial.map = crescentTexture;

    //Load 3d model
    var modelLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    modelLoader.load(
        'Models/concerto_crescent.obj',

        function (obj) {

            obj.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child.isMesh) {
                    child.material = crescentMaterial;
                }
            });
            scene.add(obj);
        },

        function (xhr) {

            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');

        },

        function (error) {

            console.log(error);

        }
    );
```

Originally it would not render at all. I added this to the web.config file as per an answer I found and it began rendering

```
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  </staticContent>
```

How the model is rendering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3CJ9.jpg

Extra Geometry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Lx3.jpg

How the model looks in Blender: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKP9e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what the problem is there. More generally though, OBJ isn't a very good format.. your materials are in a separate file, requiring you to make a THREE.MTLLoader also.. in addition to the OBJLoader... Might I suggest using GLTFLoader and exporting from blender as binary .gltf instead (.glb format) ?
With GLTF, Blender can embed the materials and textures directly in the .glb file.. neccesitating only one loader, and also supporting modern rendering features like animation, and PBR.

Comment: I switched to GLTF format and changed the mime type in that Static Content tag appropriately and it resolved the issue. Thanks for the answer, definitely won't be using .obj anymore!

Comment: Cool! Yeah you can still keep other formats around for your original assets, it's just the final delivery to the web that GLTF is really ideal.